# Как получить название переменной в виде строки?

Tags: php

Заранее прошу прощения если вопрос кому-то покажется глупым и бессмысленным, но для меня он имеет смысл. Необходима функция которая на входе получает например $var а на выходе выдаёт строку 'var' т.е. имя поданной переменной в строковом виде.
Есть какие-то способы это сделать?

Comment: reflection.....

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Напишите пожалуйста минимальный пример или дайте ссылку на ресурс, который может ответить на вопрос. Если не сложно конечно

Comment: `$func = function ( $param1, $param2 ) {
    /* some code */
};

$refFunc = new ReflectionFunction($func);
foreach ($refFunc->getParameters() as $refParameter) {
    echo $refParameter->getName(), '<br />';
}` ......... ресурс..... эм.....stackoverflow как ни странно))  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2692481/  и http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17455043/  и http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5854976/ и т.д.

Comment: Хм... странно....и ответ от And вас устроил? Но ведь это банальная передача аргумента в функцию. С таким же успехом можно было просто передавать строку в параметре

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выход только такой:

```
echo substr('$var',1);
```

То есть, если не передать переменную в одинарных кавычках, то есть в простой строке, то ничего не выйдет. В двойных кавычках переменная выполнится и вернет значение.

```
function variable($var) {
    return substr($var, 1);
}
$var1 = '$var';
echo variable($var1); // var
```

Только вот не знаю к чему это может быть пригодно.
Еще можно попробовать функцию `get_defined_vars` но она выплевывает все.

**UPD:**

```
function variable($variable, array $vars) {
    $variable = substr($variable, 1);
    $vars = isset($vars[$variable]) ? $vars[$variable] : 'null';
    return $variable . ' = '. $vars;
}
echo variable('$var', get_defined_vars()); // var = 666
```

За исключением того, что `get_defined_vars` работает только с той областью видимости, где была определена - означает, что если определим в функции, то не увидит переменную за областью видимости функции.
Смог бы увидеть `$GLOBALS`, но `registr_globals` был удален в 5.4, теперь не видит.

Comment: а как взять из переменной значение тогда? Например если он хочет передать $var со значением 666?

Answer (score -1):

Можем получить стек вызовов, вычитать строку из кода, получить переменную.

Способ явно медленный с кучей ограничений, но как пример..

```
function getVariableName($variable)
{
    $backtrace = debug_backtrace()[0];
    $file = file($backtrace['file']);
    $callLine = $file[$backtrace['line']-1];

    $result = preg_match('/' . __FUNCTION__ . ' *\([^$]*(?P<varName>\$[^ ,)]+) *\)/ui', $callLine, $matches);

    if (!$result) {
        throw new Exception('Fix regexp');
    }

    return $matches['varName'];
}


$foo = 'bar';
$baz = ['Hello', 'World'];

echo getVariableName($foo);
echo PHP_EOL;
echo getVariableName($baz);

// $foo
// $baz
```

По мотивам ответа на [en.SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19788805/2401421)